# Defining variables in one table based on values in another table

Tags: sas

I'm fairly new with SAS and am looking for a little guidance. 
I have two tables. One contains my data (something like the below, although much larger):

```
Data DataTable;
Input Var001 $ Var002;
Datalines;
000 050
063 052
015 017
997 035;
run;
```

My variables are integers (read in as text) from 000 to 999. There can be as few as two, or as many as 500 depending on what the user is doing.

The second table contains user specified groupings of the variables in the DataTable:

```
Data Var_Groupings;
input var $ range $ Group_Desc $;
Datalines;
001  025  0-25
001  075  26-75
001  999  76-999
002  030  0-30
002  050  31-50
002  060  51-60
002  999  61-999;
run;
```

(In actuality, this table in adjusted by the user in excel and then imported, but this will work for the purposes of troubleshooting).

The "var" variable in the var_groupings table corresponds to a var column in the DataTable. So for instance a "var" of 001 in the var_groupings table is saying that this grouping will be on var001 of the DataTable.

the "Range" variable specifics the upper bound of a grouping. So looking at ranges in the var_grouping table where var is equal to 001, the user wants the first group to span from 0 to 25, the second group to span from 26 to 75, and the last group to span from 76 to 999.

EDIT: The  Group_Desc column can contain any string and is not necessarily of the form presented here.

the final table should look something like this:

```
Var001  Var002  Var001_Group  Var002_group
 000     050       0-25         31-50
 063     052       26-75        51-60
 015     017       0-25         0-30
 997     035       76-999       31-50
```

I'm not sure how I would even approach something like this. Any guidance you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting one, thanks! It can be solved using CALL EXECUTE, since we need to create variable names  from values. And obviously PROC FORMAT is the easiest way to convert some values into ranges. So, combining these two things we can do something like this:

```
proc sort data=Var_Groupings; by var range; run;

/*create dataset which will be the source of our formats' descriptions*/
data formatset;
set Var_Groupings;
    by var;

    fmtname='myformat';
    type='n';
    label=Group_Desc;
    start=input(lag(range),8.)+1;
    end=input(range,8.);
    if FIRST.var then start=0;

    drop range Group_Desc;
run;


/*put the raw data into new one, which we'll change to get what we want (just to avoid 
 changing the raw one)*/
data want;
    set Datatable;
run;

/*now we iterate through all distinct variable numbers. A soon as we find new number
we generate with CALL EXECUTE three steps: PROC FORMAT, DATA-step to apply this format     
to a specific variable, and then PROC CATALOG to delete format*/

data _null_;
    set formatset;
    by var;
    if FIRST.var then do;
        call execute(cats("proc format library=work cntlin=formatset(where=(var='",var,"')); run;"));
        call execute("data want;");
        call execute("set want;");
        call execute(cats('_Var',var,'=input(var',var,',8.);'));
        call execute(cats('Var',var,'_Group=put(_Var',var,',myformat.);'));
        call execute("drop _:;");
        call execute("proc catalog catalog=work.formats; delete myformat.format; run;");
    end;
run;
```

**UPDATE**. I've changed the first DATA-step (for creating formatset) so that now end and start for each  range is taken from variable `range`, not `Group_Desc`. And PROC SORT moved to the beginning of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dmitry. I appreciate it. I am getting the following error, though. 'NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1   + proc format library=work cntlin=formatset(where=(var='002'));
ERROR: This range is repeated, or values overlap:            .-           ..
1   +                                                                   run;
'

Comment: Do you use exactly the same Var_Groupings dataset that in your question? Because error means that for variable 002 there are overlapping ranges in this dataset. But there's no overlaps in this dataset (and the code worked properly for me).

Comment: The problem seems to be in the step where you define the formats. The formatset table has missing values for columns start and end. Looking at this, its likely that this is because in my real Var_Groupings table, the Group_Desc column can be any string and not necessarily of the form (ddd-ddd). I apologize that I wasn't explicit regarding that.

Comment: Then one of the approaches would be to pre-clean Var_Groupings to ensure unified and non-overlapping ranges. Or you want to keep these descriptions "as is"? Then we'll need to use range-variable for formats' definitions. Is range-variable clean (only digits, no missing, no duplicates)?

Comment: I'd like to keep the descriptions as is. The range variables should always be populated with no duplicates. They will always be of the form above with the last range equal to 999. Again, thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: This is a thing of beauty. Thanks.